# Center the First Item of List View Programmatically

Tags: android, listview, center, listviewitem

I have a List View which have different items in it. Now what i want is to center the position of only the first item of the List view pro grammatically. Is it possible? Right now i am just disabling the clck on the first item. Following is the code for it.

```
 mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, final View view,
        int position, long id) {
       if (id==0)
       {
           mainListView.setClickable(false);
       }
       else
       {
        AlertDialog.Builder abc = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        abc.setMessage("Are you sure to delete number?");
        abc.setCancelable(true);
```

Now i want the first item of the listview i.e. id=0 to be shown in center but the rest of items in normal position. Please explain what to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: I checked that it is not working in my case

Comment: "what i want is to center the position of only the first item". You need a different row type of the first row.

Comment: Ok lemme try again